# Can you Strict Generic types or give one parameter more than one type ?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

For example i want to specify a type that might be `Integer`  or `String` and use it as special type in `func` i tried `typealias`
but it wont solve the case because typealiases can't have `or` arguments as its only uses `&` therefore consider the case below.

```
typealias alis = StringProtocol & Numeric


func foo <T: alis> (vee: T) -> T{
// do something
    return vee
}
```

i want this func to accept a parameter type of either ( `Int` or `String` )  not anything else (`<T>`),

as you can see i tried with typealias and i have no compile error.

however trying to use the function will lead to these errors.

```
foo(vee: 1) //Argument type 'Int' does not conform to expected type 'StringProtocol'
```

And

```
foo(vee: "v") //Argument type 'String' does not conform to expected type 'Numeric'
```

is this achievable with swift ? if so how.

Comment: How would you expect to conform to both simultaneously ? You can use `Any`  but probably not the best solution. What is your goal?

Comment: is it achievable ? @LeoDabus and thats what i am trying to figure out,

Comment: As I said there is no object type that I know that conforms to Numeric and StringProtocol.

Comment: the question is can we combine something to create that type of a object

Comment: using protocols or something, perhaps going into lower level apis, as stringProctol for example confirms to about 7 other protocols, can we create a homogeneous type of both with them same properties

Comment: Why don't you simply create two methods with different signatures?

Comment: @LeoDabus i know, simple Polymorphic, but the challenge in this one to either know for sure its not possible or somehow we can combine those 2 types into one

Comment: You are already doing it using StringProtocol (String and Substring)

Comment: and Numeric supports Integers and Floating point types. I wonder why would you need to support both protocols.

Comment: @LeoDabus tbh i am trying to understand lower level compiling, as i trying to create my Homo type somehow ,, researches proposes

Comment: I rather like using enums for such cases, e.g. `enum Alis { case string(String); case numeric(Int) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's suppose that you *could* use a OR operator to combine protocols, what would you be able to do with something of type `(Int | String)`?

Not everything you can do to an `Int` can be done on `(Int | String)`, because it might be a string underlyingly. Similarly, not everything you can do to an `String` can be done on `(Int | String)`, because it might be a `Int` underlyingly.

Now you might say "Ah. I know that `Int` and `String` both have a `description` property. I should be able to access `description` on a variable of type `(Int | String)`."

Well, in that case, you can just create such a protocol yourself and only have `Int` and `String` conform to it:

```
protocol IntOrString {
    var description: String { get }
}

extension Int : IntOrString {}
extension String : IntOrString {}
```

(Note that `description` is already defined in `CustomStringConvertible`. For the sake of argument, imagine that does not exist.)

Comment: great answer, so if i want to use Int or String as parameter i would be able only to perform the operators that is fine to use for both

Comment: so far this is enough for the question case .

Comment: You can only use the properties defined in the protocol. In this case the `description` property.

Comment: @Tobi Exactly as Leo Dabus said. If you want to use some other member, you need to add it in `IntOrString` protocol.

Comment: @Sweeper yeah i figured out. claps great answer