# Can I compose types in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, composition

How can I compose types similar to protocol composition in Swift?

For example, I have a `likes` data which is a dictionary with values either having `Int` or `String`, but not others.

```
likes: {
    "1": {
        "id": "l1"
        "ts": 1551796878504
        "userId": "u1"
    }
}
```

Current, I use a variable with type,

```
var likes: [String: [String: Any]]
```

but, I would like it to be of type

```
var likes: [String: [String: AlphaNum]]
```

Can I use something like `typealias AlphaNum = String & Int` or something similar, without using class or struct?

Comment: You probably mean `String | Int`, which would be fine in dynamically typed languages. It's not possible in Swift. You should rather wrap the value into a custom struct or an enum with associtated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own Protocol and let `String` and `Int` conform to it:

```
protocol ValueProtocol {}

extension String:ValueProtocol{}
extension Int:ValueProtocol{}


var likes:[String : [String:ValueProtocol]] = ["1": [
                    "id": "l1",
                    "ts": 1551796878504,
                    "userId": "u1"
                ]
            ]
```

But to use the ValueProtocols, you would also have to add functions like `getValue` to it, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question has already been answered, but it seems to me like you are trying to work with JSON, and for this reason I would highly recommend using the `Decodable`protocol in swift

> **Decodable:** A type that can decode itself from an external representation [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable)

This will easily handle all your incoming JSON, for example:

```swift
struct decodableIncomming: Decodable {
  let name: String
  let ID: Int
  let externalURL: URL
}

let json = """
{
 "name": "Robert Jhonson",
 "ID": 1234256,
 "externalURL": "http://someurl.com/helloworld"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)! // data in JSON which might be requested from a url

let decodedStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode(Swifter.self, from: json) // Decode data
print(decodedStruct) //Decoded structure ready to use
```

Comment: +1 for decodable. I am not working directly with JSON in this example. But this information certainly helps.

Comment: Ok, hope it helped, and if you ever work with JSON decodable is the best way i've found so far.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, as you can see `typealias AlphaNum = String & Int` it's `&` operator not `| \\ or` and you can't using `[String: [String: AlphaNum]]` because the inner `Dictionary` value is basically `String & Int` , a value can't be two types either one of them, look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52971389/8192960), as the answers is about creating a dummy protocol, and use that however there are no shared properties between `Int` and `String` but one, `Description`, therefore  even with dummy `protocol` you would have to cast at some point, unless you are only using `Description` referring to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52971632/8192960),

```
 protocol IntOrString {
    var description: String { get }
}

extension Int : IntOrString {}
extension String : IntOrString {}
```

And using it like this, `var likes: [String: [String: IntOrString]]` .

After getting into the `IntOrString` value you may use `.description` property .